# Does Quick lauch in Visual Studio have the same purpose as Command Palette in Visual Studio Code

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-code

I have some experience working in VS code and I recently started using Visual Studio 2017. It appears to me that the Quick Launch in Visual Studio (opened by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Q</kbd>) is quite similar to VS Code's Command Palette
(<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd>). Are they used for the same purposes or is there some significant difference between them?

Comment: They show different content - the command palette shows all available commands, and Quick Launch shows all the views. That seems like a significant difference, so maybe I don't understand what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the closet analog for VS Code Command Palette (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd>) in VS is Command Window (Views -> Other Windows -> Command Window) or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>.